# Regular expression requiring one word, avoiding another

Tags: .net, regex

I'm analyzing file names using Regex, and I need to find 2 types of files which will be in a specific folder. The naming convention is:

```
DOCUMENTS/COMPANYID.Name of Disclosure.YYYYMMDD.pdf
DOCUMENTS/COMPANYID.Some Other Document.YYYYMMDD.pdf
```

I'm struggling to find the right combinations...

Using this regex finds the "Some Other Document" above (does NOT contain "Disclosure")

```
^DOCUMENTS/(?:(?!Disclosure).)*.pdf$
```

The problem is that finds anything within subfolders of DOCUMENTS as well - which is a problem.  I need to find only the exact path (one folder/ and then the name).

In other words, this should NOT match:

```
DOCUMENTS/processed/COMPANYID.Some Other Document.YYYYMMDD.pdf
```

Could someone guide me on the Regex to

^ONLYONEDIRECTORY/Name includes Disclosure.pdf$

^ONLYONEDIRECTORY/Name does NOT include Disclosure.pdf$

Comment: Try changing the dot to `'[^/]`: ie `^DOCUMENTS/(?:(?!Disclosure)[^/])*pdf$`

Comment: Great!  That does work to eliminate files in a subdirectory - thank you!   Can you tell me how to change that statement to find the files the DO contain the word "Disclosure"?

Comment: Must the file name contain `Disclosure`? Must it end with `Disclosure.pdf`? Do you want to ignore files without `Disclosure`? Perhaps the regex you want is `^ONLYONEDIRECTORY/[^/.]+ Disclosure[^/.]*\.pdf$`. If you want to match file names both with and without `Disclosure` then try `^ONLYONEDIRECTORY/[^/.]+\.pdf$`.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not end with the word disclosure, there are some other date parameters and so on that may follow.   I just need a regular expression that requires the word Disclosure anywhere in the name, but only in the first directory layer.   I'll try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^DOCUMENTS/(?![^/]*Disclosure)[^/]*\.pdf$
^DOCUMENTS/(?=[^/]*Disclosure)[^/]*\.pdf$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/Ebu7kC/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/Ebu7kC/4).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `DOCUMENTS/` - a literal string
- `(?![^/]*Disclosure)` -  a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than `/` and then `Disclosure` substring immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?=[^/]*Disclosure)` -  a *positive lookahead* that fails the match if there are NO zero or more chars other than `/` and then `Disclosure` substring immediately to the right of the current location
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\.pdf` - `.pdf` string
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks you!  That works perfectly!  Marking as answer.